# Petalinux 2020.1 config failed

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, yocto, xilinx, petalinux

I am trying to setup petalinux 2020.1 in ubuntu 18.04.4 docker environment. I have created the docker image following [this link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-convert-an-iso-to-a-docker-image/) and created the docker container from [this repo](https://github.com/z4yx/petalinux-docker) . I am able to create a petalinux project with the following command

```
$ petalinux-create -t project -s /host/xilinx-zcu102-v2020.1-final.bsp
INFO: Create project:
INFO: Projects:
INFO:   * xilinx-zcu102-2020.1
INFO: has been successfully installed to /home/vivado/
INFO: New project successfully created in /home/vivado/
```

but then when I try to config I get the following error

```
$ cd xilinx-zcu102-2020.1/
vivado@a20176:~/xilinx-zcu102-2020.1$ petalinux-config
INFO: sourcing build tools
[INFO] generating Kconfig for project
[INFO] menuconfig project


*** End of the configuration.
*** Execute 'make' to start the build or try 'make help'.

[INFO] extracting yocto SDK to components/yocto
ERROR: Failed to Extract Yocto SDK.
ERROR: Failed to config project.
$ cat build/config.log
[INFO] generating Kconfig for project
INFO: [Hsi 55-2053] elapsed time for repository (/opt/Xilinx/petalinux/tools/xsct/data/embeddedsw) loading 0 seconds
hsi::open_hw_design: Time (s): cpu = 00:00:07 ; elapsed = 00:00:05 . Memory (MB): peak = 1523.867 ; gain = 727.504 ; free physical = 905 ; free virtual = 27460
[INFO] menuconfig project
/home/vivado/xilinx-zcu102-2020.1/build/misc/config/Kconfig.syshw:29:warning: defaults for choice values not supported
[INFO] extracting yocto SDK to components/yocto
PetaLinux Extensible SDK installer version 2020.1
=================================================
ERROR: the installer requires the en_US.UTF-8 locale to be installed (but not selected), please install it first
ERROR: Failed to Extract Yocto SDK.
ERROR: Failed to config project.
```

I have followed all possible instructions from Xilinx forums but none of them worked. I have tried the following things-

1. manually set locale
2. use different base docker images (centos-7, ubuntu 18.04.4, ubuntu 18.04.5, ubuntu 16.04.5)

I am not sure how to get the locale issue resolved. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just got the problem resolved. Turns out if I install petalinux 2020.1 and the sdk in /opt I receive the error as above. If I install them in the home directory the problem is resolved.